# Extract Entities and Relationships

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

Given text documents (student essays with about 100 words per essay) I want to extract entities and relationships important to the context of the sentence (maybe by considering **Noun Phrase** and **Verb Phrase**) to automatically score the answer.

Are there any popular algorithms/tools that I can use to perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could be more specific, but in general this problem is known as **Information Extraction**. One example software package that deals with it is Standford NLP's [open information extraction](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html) system. Example use:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Well, I have set of essays (technical) written by students. In order to perform automatic answer scoring I want to extract important entities and relationships among them in each sentence. Also understanding the negation is important.

Comment: I see. Information extraction doesn't have a super high degree of precision - it works best when the price of failure is small - so I would strongly discourage you from using it for grading anyone. That said, you can read about a practical application on technical documents, including the difficulties of dealing with negation, [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3676897/#S2title).

Comment: No, this is only for an experiment. Not to grade students for real

Comment: Ah, OK - have fun then! 